# html5 video m3u8: How to auto play the video?

Tags: html, html5-video, m3u8

```
<video id="videoHTML5" class="video" width="100%" height="400" poster="img/poster.png" autoplay controls>
   <source src="http://IP/live/stage.stream/playlist.m3u8" >
</video>


<script>
    var vdo = document.getElementById('videoHTML5');
    vdo.src = 'http://IP/live/stage.stream/playlist.m3u8';
    vdo.load(); 
    vdo.play(); 
</script>
```

**NEVER starts ! I need to press the PLAY button on ipad and adroid !**

Any idea on how to autostart an m3u8 video ?

reagards

Answer (score 0):

you can try autoplay="true" in your  code